# how to disable "free" user input in eonasdan-datetimepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Is there any way to disable "free" user input eonasdan-datetimepicker? My goal is to force user to select the dates using the picker and completely disallow entering dates manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, you have to add to your `input-group` the attribute `readonly`. It disables the user input but still accepts data. Should be the same with eonasdan-datetimepicker.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RR4hw/1377/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It turned out quite simple!